# My Blog App Has Been Crashed

Tags: java, android

here i have a question. I have already make my blog app. But, when i run this app, suddenly it crashed. Here my source code

```
    package blog.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    private WebView myWebView;
    private WebSettings myWebSettings;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        WebView myWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://teknorats.blogspot.com");
        WebSettings myWebSettings=myWebView.getSettings();
        myWebSettings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebVewClient());

    }

    private static class WebVewClient extends WebViewClient {

        public WebVewClient() {
        }
    }

    public class WebAppInterface{
        Context mContext;
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext=c;
        }

        private WebAppInterface() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
         public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(),"Android");

    }
    }

    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

And this is the xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:src="@drawable/tr_launcher"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

Please, i need your correction with that code.

If you ask where i got this code, i got this code from here http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: If it crashed, you should have a stack trace. You should include that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that in your xml file `LinearLayout`  tag has id `webview` and you are trying to get 
cast `LinearLayout` to `WebView`.

So change

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:src="@drawable/tr_launcher"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

to

```
<Webview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview">
</Webview>
```

and you  has already defined `myWebView` as class variable so change

```
WebView myWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

to

```
myWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

Comment: I was changed <LinearLayout...</LinearLayout> to <WebView...</WebView> . But its still crashed.

Comment: @AriFazola Please clear your project and retry.Also add crash report in question.

Comment: its mean that i must delete this project and retyping? or just clean project and copy-paste that code?
This may the crash report: when i run this app, then it show a messege like this "Unfortunately, MainActivity has stopped"

Comment: Just clean project and retry,and also post complete crash report from logs